# Using FileSystemWatcher with multiple directories

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

Using a `FileSystemWatcher`, how do I track whether new files of a specific extension have been created across multiple directories?

Answer (score 1):

Set the [FileSystemWatcher.Filter Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.filter%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to the filename extension you're interested in.

Also take a look at the [FileSystemWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.includesubdirectories%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

The link has an example.

Comment: @jay i need to include multiple directories not subdirecotryes

Comment: EnableRaisingEvent = true, you can ignore directories you do not want in Created event handler

Comment: @hungry nope u are misunderstand. i have: \\server1\dir1, \\server2\dir2 etc

Comment: @joe - you'll have to set up a FSW for each folder then.

Comment: @Joe, set up FSW for any folder which contains all your target folder and ignore which you do not want to handle. Otherwise create n instance each for separate folder, and use single handler for Created Event

Answer (score 0):

You can include only subdirectories. to listen for changes in other directories you'll need more FileSystemWatchers

Comment: If you can make one FileSystemWatcher you can make two or more right?

Comment: BTW: you can only watch folders on a Windows system if want to monitor directories on other machines.

Comment: Have a look at all the Related posts in this forum on the right of this page.